# Force IP in the url?

Tags: google-chrome, url, firefox

Is there a standard way to force the browser to resolve a certain domain name to a specified IP?

Fictive example: http://www.notregistered.com=192.168.0.1:8080/homepage.html

I'd need that to show (work in progress) websites to end users before the domain name has been set to the right server.

If not is there a way with FireFox & Chrome?

Comment: DNS is just an help, behind the scenes all this is at least resolved to IP anyway. Depending on your configuration, you might need a way to differentiate websites hosted on the same machine though, and if you wish to use Ip's then you'll need to differentiate using port number...

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can edit your `/etc/hosts` file to force a host name to map to a specific IP address, as in:

```
127.0.0.1  www.example.com
```

Similar information is [available on the web](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) for both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score -3):

Juste use 192.168.0.1:8080/homepage.html and it will work
You can visit Google at http://216.58.208.67/ for exemple

Comment: The server and the website need the domain's name to work properly.

Comment: So (in a windows environement) you can edit the host file to make your computer think www.domain.do is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (IP)
Must be possible in a Linux PC